# linking contact form to an email HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm trying to make the Contact us form working,

P.S. I'm not a Developer, my coding skills is very limited.

this is the HTML code: (from a template with some adjustments)

```html
<!--Contact Starts -->
<div class="container contactform center">
<h2 class="text-center  wowload fadeInUp">Get in touch</h2>
  <div class="row wowload fadeInLeftBig">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject">
        <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>

      </div>
  </div>
```

and this is the PHP script: (wrote it myself)

```html
$name = $_POST['Name'] ;
$from = $_POST['Email'] ;
$message = $_POST['Message'] ;
$to = "contact@mywebsite.com" ;
$subject = "Website Contact Form" ;

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name . $company . $email) ;
echo "Your Message Has Been Sent" ;
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong, but it's not workign.

the php file called emailscript.php located at /assets/php/emailscript.php

right now I'm getting an error this error: "Not Found

The requested document was not found on this server."

Comment: where is your <form> tag with action attribute ?

Comment: Where is form tag.And each form element should have name attribute

Comment: sorry i forgot to copy/past: <form action="/assets/php/emailscript.php" method="post" name="contactform"> it's right above the HTML code i posted

Comment: right now it shows that the /assets/php/emailscript.php file is not found , so please check your path and write it again

Comment: that's the thing, im sure about the path

Comment: yes put emailscript.php in same folder where you have created this file or else you need to use ../

Comment: Or just remove "/" from beginning of your path ! (it depends where your form hosted) !

Comment: the HTML code is in the index.html file at the root. the PHP file path is /assets/php/emailscript.php

Comment: i removed the "/", still the same issue.

Comment: try with this  <form action="../assets/php/emailscript.php" method="post" name="contactform">

Comment: actually there way atypo in the PHP bath, but even after adding the right path, and doing what you guys suggested, im now getting a new error  (Internal Server Error) [link](http://prntscr.com/d2328y)

Comment: @Balagosh I tried ur code.I answered it.Please try that .If ur path is correct it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to this...

```html
<!--Contact Starts -->
<div class="container contactform center">
<h2 class="text-center  wowload fadeInUp">Get in touch</h2>
  <div class="row wowload fadeInLeftBig">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <form action="/assets/php/emailscript.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Company" name="Company">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="Subject">
          <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
        </form>

      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: [UPDATE] im getting the echo message but im not getting the test email to my inbox

Comment: [UPDATE 2 ] actually it's working!!! the email went to the spam folder im not sure why, but it's working now... THANK YOU GUYS.. really appreciate your effort :)

Comment: Okay Well come  :)   please up question if this useful

Answer (score 0):

Please put your form elements in `<form>` tag. And give each element a name attribute.by using name attribute we will get form data in php.

```
 <form name="contact" action="/assets/php/emailscript.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="contact_name">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Company" name="company">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject"> 
 <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
 <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for the quick respons, i tried that..  still the same error

Comment: Please check the path of file

Comment: Put  var_dump($_POST); at beggining to check whwther it raches in php

Comment: i did, now im not getting an error, but blank page.

Answer (score -2):

Encircle your code in isset function to avoid any error

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Name']))
{

    $name=$_POST['Name'] ;
    $from=$_POST['Email'] ;
    $message=$_POST['Message'] ;
    $to="contact@mywebsite.com" ;
    $subject="Website Contact Form" ;

    mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name . $company . $email) ;
    // it echo not eco
    echo "Your Message Has Been Sent" ;

}
?>
```